# PyPi refuses version value

Tags: python, pip, upload, pypi

I am trying to upload package to pypi and getting error:

> '4.5.1-2021.2-0' is an invalid value for Version. Error: Start and end with a letter or numeral containing only ASCII numeric and '.', '_' and '-'. See https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata for more information.

I know that my name is not [PEP440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/) compliant, but it matches PyPi value format. Strange, that it substitites `_` to `-`

From `setup.py`:

```
setuptools.setup(
    name="opencv-python-inference-engine",
    version="4.5.1_2021.2_0",
...
```

Package filename: `opencv_python_inference_engine-4.5.1_2021.2_0-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`

What I am doing wrong, except PRP440 compliance?

**UPD:** '4.5.1-2021.2' also generates error, however it looks PEP440 compliant (pre-release separators).

Comment: You write *"I know that my name is not PEP440."* while [PyPi docs](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata/#version) says *"This field must be in the format specified in PEP 440"* Do you see the problem? :)

Comment: @DeepSpace Well, it gives an error with different text, but I see your point:) I tried '4.5.1-2021.2', it  also generates error, however it looks PEP440 compliant (pre-release separators).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your version isn't PEP440 compliant. Prerelease versions have to include the prerelease "phase" (alpha, beta, release candidate).

> The pre-release segment consists of an alphabetical identifier for the pre-release phase, along with a non-negative integer value. Pre-releases for a given release are ordered first by phase (alpha, beta, release candidate) and then by the numerical component within that phase.

```
X.YaN   # Alpha release
X.YbN   # Beta release
X.YrcN  # Release Candidate
X.Y     # Final release
```

For alpha this means the letter `a`, for beta this means the letter `b`, and for Release Candidate you need `rc`. Change your dash to an `a` or `b` and I think it will work.

Comment: hmm, can I combine in a single release value both major.minor.micro and date based release?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow? There's a few ways you can incorporate calendar based versioning in- YY.MM.DD for example.

Comment: Yeah, like could I incorporate *both* calendar ans X.Y.Z versioning? E.g., X.Y.Z-YY.MM.DD

Comment: Then I could go with X.Y.ZcYYMMDD. The reason this works is that "c" is allowed by PEP440 as an alias for "rc", but in this case you can tell people it's actually calendar. The downside to this is it does limit you to one release a day though, which can be an issue when pushing out emergency fixes.

Comment: @banderlog013 If you wish to make [dependency hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell) a bit "less hellish" for your package's users, please stick to X.Y.Z (drop the date part) and follow [semver](http://www.semver.org)